# vundle#rc() function call error

Tags: vim, vundle

Hello I am trying to install some plugins and use vundle as my plugin manager.

When I open gvim this is the error that I get

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:
line    9:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc
line   12:
E492: Not an editor command: Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
```

And here is the snippet of the top of my .vimrc file

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundel/
call vundle#rc()

"Required Bundel Statement 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'


"User Installed Bundles
Bundle 'neocomplcache/neocomplcache.vim'
Bunlde 'perlomni/perlomni.vim'


filetype plugin indent on
filetype on
syntax on
```

I installed it according to git hub and according to the read me that was downloaded with it.

I do not have access to a super user account so trying to unistall and reinstall vim will not work.

Also I tried installing pathogen and that worked for some bundles but would not work for perlomni.vim because it was an ftplugin and pathogen was not appending the bundles correctly and after research I saw most people saying vundle was better than pathogen.

Can anyone help me get my bundles working correctly?

I am trying to use either bundles downloaded from a git repository or a bundles that are stored on a shared root directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You spelled vundle wrong in your `set rtp` line

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundel/
```

should probably be

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
```

Comment: ^^^ I did.....so when install bundles do you have to do the git clone commands yourself into the directory where you want them installed then set up the Bundle command to that directory? When ever I am running the BundleInstall it keeps trying to reinstall them. If I install them my self i should just be ablt to set the Bunle 'mydir/destbundle.vim' and it should be good to go right? In that case I can make any directory that I want to install these plugins into then cd into that directory and execute the git clone cammand there correct?

Comment: @user2479059 I don't use vundle, I have only used pathogen. But from my understanding you should not install the bundles your self. vundle should take care of all that for you. So adding `Bundle 'mydir/destbundle.vim'` vundle will go off (after a BundleInstall) and do a git clone for you. I do not know if you can add directories yourself.

Comment: ^^^  I started out using pathogen and that worked for some of my bundles that I was trying to use but it wouldnt work for bundles like perlomni........should I try switching back to pathogen? It seems like both have their unsubtletees with what you can and cant install easily and have to use workarounds for everything else.